# Why doesn't Quantum Turing Machine contradict with Church-Turing thesis

Tags: complexity-theory

I studied about Quantum Turing machine and i figured out that the difference between QTM and TM is in transition function and also if a problem is unsolvable by a TM then it is unsolvable by a QTM but I need a justifiable reason to claim QTM does not contradict with Church-Turing thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantum Turing machines can be simulated by classical Turing machines. See Deutsch's fundamental paper [Quantum theory, the Church-Turing principle and the universal
quantum computer](http://old.ceid.upatras.gr/tech_news/papers/quantum_theory.pdf).

Comment: Can classical Turing machine simulate the Quantum Turing machine with at most polynomial slowdown? Are there some references?

Comment: Okay, I found an answer in this problem [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117043/can-current-quantum-computers-decide-languages-that-turing-machines-cannot).